# Specifying File Type in Premake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, premake

I'm using Premake with Visual Studio. My project contains normal *.h, *.cpp and *.inl files. I want to force Visual Studio to treat *.inl files as **C/C++ header** files (this can be set manually through the File Properties window under "Item Type").

By default, Premake sets them as "Does not participate in build".

Is there any way to do this in Premake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in [PR 710](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pull/710) (authored by @Zeenobit, thanks for that!).

Comment: No problem! I still feel like it should be customizable by the user, but I couldn't think of a nice interface for it, and I don't know enough about internal Premake code. So maybe a feature request for future! :)